# Converting  ISO 8601 format to d M Y in PHP

Tags: php

PHP code:

```
echo date("c");  //out put like this 2012-06-19T20:37:44+05:30   
echo date("d M, Y");  //out put "Jun 19,2012"

$time=date("c");
echo date("d M, Y",$time);// This is not working. What could the reason be?
```

My requirement is to convert ISO8601 format to 'd M ,Y'. I need it in this format to use with the [timeago jQuery plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/).

Comment: You want this functionality in jQuery or PHP?  The title and body of your post are contradicting each other...

Comment: [Alternative answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11104438/212940) posted for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function.

```
echo date("d M, Y",strtotime(date("c")));
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use PHP's [DateTime](http://www.php.net/datetime) object to perform the conversion:-

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, date('c'));
echo $dateTime->format('d M Y');
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the second argument to date is expected to be a timestamp, you are passing a string. Use [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) to convert your date to into a timestamp:

```
$time = date("c");
echo date("d M, Y", strtotime($time));
```