# Displaying actual time using iso 8601

Tags: php, timestamp, iso8601

I m referring to this: [Converting  ISO 8601 format to d M Y in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104068/converting-iso-8601-format-to-d-m-y-in-php/36120497?noredirect=1#comment59881584_36120497)

I tried this same as this:  `echo date("d M Y H:i:s", strtotime($time));`

But time is not shown as saved in database. Its showing few hours difference.

Database has: 2016-03-20T23:30:51+00:00

With above php echo i get: 21 Mar 2016 00:30:51
Where as it must be 20 Mar 2016 23:30:51

Above example shows additional of 1 hour y?
I tried using this format to display hour & minute but time shown is wrong. Time display has few hours difference. Why is this so?

Comment: can you show original string from database?

Comment: It looks like strtotime and date use different timezones somehow. Can we see an example of the contents of the `$time` variable?

Comment: Details updated in the question. yes timezones are different.

Comment: @fusion3k Database has: `2016-03-20T23:30:51+00:00`

With above php echo i get: 21 Mar 2016 00:30:51 Where as it must be 20 Mar 2016 23:30:51

Comment: The date is in GMT. So if the difference between GMT and your timezone is 5 hours, your result is yet correct.

Comment: Or you want obtain the original GMT date.

Comment: Its correct? you mean its showing me as per my timezone? How about original? @fusion3k

Comment: Dublin (Ireland) `Sunday, 20 March 2016, 23:30:00`
Bengaluru (India - Karnataka) `Monday, 21 March 2016, 05:00:00` but is displaying: `21 Mar 2016 00:30:51`

Answer (score 2):

Your date format `2016-03-20T23:30:51+00:00` reveals a GMT DateTime (side note: the same TimeZone used by php/unix timestamps).

So when you write:

```
echo date( "d M Y H:i:s", strtotime( $time ) );
```

You obtain yet the correct date converted in your system TimeZone.

You can use `DateTime` class to perform more operations with dates:

```
$date = new DateTime( $time );
echo $date->format("d M Y H:i:s");
```

will print the date in original (GMT) format.

```
$date->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin') );
echo $date->format("d M Y H:i:s");
```

will print the date in 'Europe/Berlin' Timezone.

---

Side note: saving dates in ISO 8601 UTC/GMT is actually the best choice.

---

- Read more about [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- Read more about [DateTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)

Comment: The timezone in Local Server is: UTC+05:30 (India)
Database value is (GMT-3) (chile) 
If value of chile in DB is `2016-03-20T23:30:51+00:00` then in india it would be around `2016-03-21T05:00:51` which ain't returning proper yet!

Comment: `+00:00` mean UTC/GMT Basing on my above example, create `$date = new DateTime( $time );` and then `echo $date->getTimezone->getName();` to see it. The date is UTC/GMT format 100% See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: My data is on `$row_MultipleLOPStatus["TimeUpdated"]` can you help me with full code for it. @fusion3k sorry yes time stored was gmt. - dublin time

Comment: If you want date in your local timezone system you have it yet, because php `date` function print dates in your local `default_timezone`. If you never set this variable you can put at top of your script `date_default_timezone_set ( string 'Ireland/Dublin' )` ore modify your php.ini file the line with `date.timezone`. Otherwise use my above example: simply replace `$time` with your GMT time string/variable.

Comment: Dublin (Ireland) `Sunday, 20 March 2016, 23:30:00`
Bengaluru (India - Karnataka) `Monday, 21 March 2016, 05:00:00` but is displaying: `21 Mar 2016 00:30:51`

Comment: have you read my answer? without changing timezone your ISO format set the date in GMT.

Comment: receiving an error as : Fatal error Call to a member function setTimezone() on a non-object in ... 
I used following: `<?php $date->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin') );
echo $date->format("d M Y H:i:s");?>` @fusion3k
I need value from this: $row_MultipleLOPStatus["TimeUpdated"]

Comment: Mohammed, when you see an error like this double check your code, please. This is not a free code service. See this [demo](https://eval.in/539525) : the example is correct. Compare it with your code and find the syntax error. This has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: thanks a lot. this got it right. thank you once again.

Comment: Finally! An answer that actually explains it properly. Been going insane how to get the proper date/time from an ISO format. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Your system is using its local timezone instead of UTC, whereas the database is in UTC. If you wish to display in UTC, you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php to set the timezone to UTC before calling strtotime and date.