# Convert String (ISO) to Date PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to convert a string to a date in `PHP`. The string I receive is formatted:-

```
"2016-07-16T1:22:04.324+1030"
```

OR

```
"2016-12-20T03:24:59.000Z"
```

When I try this

```
$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("c", $exp);
$expirationDate = $newFormat->getTimestamp();
```

`DateTime` fails. Even when I try

```
$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat(ISO8601, $exp;
$expirationDate = $newFormat->getTimestamp();
```

`DateTime` still fails.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: First of all ISO8601 date format with miliseconds is only one: `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.sss]`. So your strings is't ISO861.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this:-

```
<?php

$time = "2016-07-16T1:22:04.324+1030";

echo date("d M, Y",strtotime(date($time)));

?>
```

Output:- 16 Jul, 2016 :- https://eval.in/594695

Reference taken:-

[Converting  ISO 8601 format to d M Y in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104068/converting-iso-8601-format-to-d-m-y-in-php)

Note:- you can change format of date according to your convenience. like `D M d Y h:i:s O T` . I checked this code on PHP 5.5.4 , PHP 5.5.14, PHP 7

Comment: This works great for a string in this format `"2016-07-16T1:22:04.324+1030"` but it gives me a negative number when putting in `"2016-12-20T03:24:59.000Z"`

Comment: I saw it works on your link. After looking into it when I pulled just the `date()` out and put in my date `2016-12-20T03:24:59.000Z` it outputs `2017-07-10MDT13:57:37.000-21600` So when I take the `strtotime()` it gives a negative number since that function dosent like my date.

Comment: When running `date("2016-12-20T03:24:59.000Z")` the output is `2017-07-10MDT13:57:37.000-21600` This is why I get a negative number out of `date("d M, Y",strtotime(date($time)));`

Comment: You are correct. I do not know why in my code it would output that weird date when it works everywhere else.

Comment: Why would you run `date()` function over already formated datetime? `T` part is replaced with timezone abbreviation in this case...

Comment: For the case of `"2016-12-20T03:24:59.000Z"` I did `date("d M, Y",strtotime($time));` and for `"2016-07-16T1:22:04.324+1030"` I did `date("d M, Y",strtotime(date($time)));` and it worked. I appreciate all the help

Comment: @bobthegoalie what i can say. Thanks for your time too

Answer (score 3):

The `date format` you were passing over here is not the one that you were comparing within your function it should be like as

```
$exp = "2016-07-16T1:22:04.324+1030";
$newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TG:i:s.uO",$exp);
echo $newDate->format("Y-m-d H:i:s O");//2016-07-16 01:22:04 +1030
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateval="2016-07-16T1:22:04.324+1030";
$dateval=str_replace("T"," T",$dateval);

$date = new DateTime($dateval);
echo $date->format('D M d Y h:i:s O T');//outputs your given time
echo "<br />";
```

or

```
echo date("D M d Y h:i:s O T",strtotime($dateval));//outputs your based on your timezone time
```

Hope it wll help

Answer (score 0):

Though I am answering this question much later than the question was asked, I feel that following points will help substantiate the answers already provided.

**Important points to keep in mind while using strtotime function:**

**1. Year is in two digit**: If year is specified in the string in two digit, then values between 00-69 are mapped to 2000-2069 and 70-99 to 1970-1999. Possible difference may arise in 32 bit.

**2. Use of Separator**: Unexpected output may arise with the use of separator. The separator slash ("/") will indicate PHP that date is in American Format i.e. m/d/y. While the separator dash or dot ("-" or ".") will let PHP will assume European format i.e. d-m-y. Further, if the year is specified in two digit with a dash separator then PHP will assume it as y-m-d format.

**3. Timestamp Range**: The Typical valid timestamp ranges from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC which represent the minimum and maximum 32 bit signed integer. However for a 64 bit version of PHP, valid range of a timestamp is virtually infinite.

**4. Checking if string is a valid timestamp**: The string supplied as parameter in strtotime function can provide different result with different version.
PHP earlier than 5.1.0 will return **-1** on failure while later version will return **false**

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php